# Rx.js can't get past values

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs5

I am trying to get the last 3 values emitted, with the code bellow I am expecting that after populating uiOrder and calling cancelOrderItem() for few times I can get access to last 3 revisions of the order with getHistory(), but I am actually getting the last (current) value 3 times, i have tried replaySubject(3) with the same results.
this is my code:

```
export class OrdersService {

  public readonly orders: Observable<Order[]>;
  public readonly uiOrder: Observable<Order>;

  private _orders: BehaviorSubject<Order[]>;
  private _uiOrder: BehaviorSubject<Order>;

  private dataStore: {
    uiOrder: Order,
    orders: Order[]
 };


  constructor() {

    this.dataStore = {
      uiOrder: null,
      orders: []
    };

    this._orders = <BehaviorSubject<Order[]>>new BehaviorSubject([]);
    this._uiOrder = <BehaviorSubject<Order>>new BehaviorSubject({});
    this.orders = this._orders.asObservable();
    this.uiOrder = this._uiOrder.asObservable();
  }

  getOrder(orderId: number | string) {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.dataStore.orders.length; i++) {
      if (this.dataStore.orders[i].id == orderId) {
        this.dataStore.orders[i].lastAccess = moment().format().slice(0, 19) + 'Z';
        this.dataStore.uiOrder = this.dataStore.orders[i];
        this.updateUiOrder();
      }
    }
  }


  cancelOrderItem(action) {
    this.dataStore.uiOrder.sections[action.sectionIndex].orderDetails.splice(action.orderDetailsIndex, 1);
    this.updateUiOrder()
  }

  getHistory() {
    this.uiOrder.take(3).subscribe((res) => {
      console.log('uiOrder', res);
    }).unsubscribe()
  }

  updateUiOrder() {
    console.log('updating ui order');
    this._uiOrder.next(this.dataStore.uiOrder);
  }

}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator you are looking for is [`bufferCount(3,1)`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-bufferCount) which creates a sliding window of the last 3 values emitted. Downside: it will only start emitting after 3 values have been accumulated. If you want to have the first value you can do something like this:

```
Rx.Observable.from([null,null])
  .concat(this.uiOrder)
  .bufferCount(3,1)
  .subscribe(uiOrderHistory => ... );
```

That way your marble diagram will look as follows:

```
---Order1-----------------Order2--------------------Order3
bufferCount(3,1)
---[null,null,Order1]-----[null,Order1,Order2]------[Order1,Order2,Order3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be overthinking it. If you need the most recent 3 orders available at any time, why not store them in an array that gets updated every time `uiOrder` emits a new order?

```
orderHistory:Order[] = [];

orders$ = this.uiOrder.subscribe(order =>
   let h = this.orderHistory;
   //add the order to history array:
   h = [...h, order];
   //splice the array to keep only the last 3 orders:
   if (h.length > 3) h.splice(0,h.length-3)
);
```

Now whenever you want to know the most recent 3 orders, just look at `orderHistory`. As a bonus, that lookup is a synchronous operation.

Comment: i thought about this approach, but isn't the point of Observables to supply values over time?

Comment: @MoshikHasky I first wrote up an answer using just Observables but changed my mind bc it was unnecessarily complex -- it used a secondary stream that would watch the first and would use the [`scan`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/scan.html) operator to track and emit the last 3 orders in an array everytime the source emitted a new order. Because this is a much simpler, easier to read and debug approach, I think it's superior. Not to mention less resource-hungry since there is no need to setup new objects, new streams, new observers...

Comment: i will mark your answer, but just for my understading Observables better, can you share how  a piece of code with scan will look like?

Comment: @MoshikHasky The answer from @MarkvanStraten is all-observables and is more elegant than the one I originally wrote! I didn't know about the `bufferCount` operator, which he demonstrated

Answer (score -1):

```
getHistory() {
this.uiOrder.takeLast(3).subscribe((res) => {
  console.log('uiOrder', res);
}).unsubscribe()  }
```

[takeLast](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-takeLast)  operator retrieves the last three values emitted from the source observable.

Comment: Thanks but takeLast(n) will emit the last n values only after the source is completed and this not the behavior I am looking for.